# I have permanent home-brew lines when I open Iterm2. How do I permanently delete from terminal?

Tags: bash

```
Example usage:
  brew search TEXT|/REGEX/
  brew info [FORMULA|CASK...]
  brew install FORMULA|CASK...
  brew update
  brew upgrade [FORMULA|CASK...]
  brew uninstall FORMULA|CASK...
  brew list [FORMULA|CASK...]

Troubleshooting:
  brew config
  brew doctor
  brew install --verbose --debug FORMULA|CASK

Contributing:
  brew create URL [--no-fetch]
  brew edit [FORMULA|CASK...]

Further help:
  brew commands
  brew help [COMMAND]
  man brew
  https://docs.brew.sh
```

Comment: I reformatted under the assumption that you are attempting to illustrate when appears when you open a terminal.

Comment: Look at your .bashrc startup file and other startup files, there must be a call to `brew`in one of them.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: iTerm2 is a macOS app. If you're using macOS and not Ubuntu, ask on [apple.se] or [unix.se].

Comment: Cross-posted as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444738/how-do-you-delete-permit-lines-on-iterm2-running-ios